# PayPal API endpoint to fetch Customers data

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am building an integration with PayPal REST API and looking to fetch Customers data of a merchant.
From the API Documentation of PayPal, it seems **Identity resource** - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1. *(documentation seems to be a little misleading)*

However upon querying it, it provides merchant user data/profile data. Is there any other way I can retrieve a merchant's customers with their ID's ideally?

Also if this info is not directly available via PayPal ? Would Ebay be a choice given its a parent company?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ebay and PayPal are not the same company, that was six years ago.

A merchant can download their transaction history in https://www.paypal.com by going to Activity -> All Reports.

Much less usefully, there is a [Transaction Search API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/). If you enable the required permission for a Client ID but have already used that Client ID to obtain an access token, wait 9 hours for the new scope.

Comment: Thanks Preston. However for Customers, I am looking for first_name, last_name, email_address, address and id of a customer. This customer is the one which has bought some items from a merchant. Is there a resource where one can scrape customer data? I thought Identity API would help but it offers only merchant profile data.

Comment: See my answer, that is what is available